# Confuse in if-else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

ok, i get a little bit confused on the `if-else statement`. I have 4 row in my `table layout` and each row will be checked to see whether it has value or not.

**Case 1**

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) 
{
    if ((i != null && i.trim().length() > 0))
    {
        WD.insertWorkDetails(a1, W1, P1, b, c);  //row 1
        WD.insertWorkDetails(a2, W2, P2, d, e1); //row 2
        WD.insertWorkDetails(a3, W3, P3, f, g);  //row 3
        WD.insertWorkDetails(a4, W4, P4, h, i);  //row 4
        ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather, date, status, b, i);
        WF.insertWorkForce(subContractors, noPeople, noHours);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "4 Row has value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(i) && (g != null && g.trim().length() > 0))
    {
        if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(W4)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(P4)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(h)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(i)))
        {
             WD.insertWorkDetails(a1, W1, P1, b, c);
             WD.insertWorkDetails(a2, W2, P2, d, e1);
             WD.insertWorkDetails(a3, W3, P3, f, g);
             ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather, date, status, b, g);
             WF.insertWorkForce(subContractors, noPeople, noHours);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Row 4 no value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } 
         else
         {
             database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
             WD.insertWorkDetails(a1, W1, P1, b, c);
             WD.insertWorkDetails(a2, W2, P2, d, e1);
             WD.insertWorkDetails(a3, W3, P3, f, g);
             WD.insertWorkDetails(a4, W4, P4, h, i);
             ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather, date, status, b, g);
             WF.insertWorkForce(subContractors, noPeople, noHours);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " All Row has value ", 
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
}
```

In case 1, `g!=null` and `w4` holds a value, but I get `Row 4 no value` which suppose to return `All Row has value`. Why?

**Case 2**

```
else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(i) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(g) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(e1)) && (c != null && c.trim().length() > 0)))
{
    if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(W4)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(P4))
        && (TextUtils.isEmpty(h)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(i))
        && ((TextUtils.isEmpty(W3)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(P3))
        && (TextUtils.isEmpty(f)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(g))) 
        && ((TextUtils.isEmpty(W2))  && (TextUtils.isEmpty(P2))
        && (TextUtils.isEmpty(d)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(e1))))
    {
        ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather, date, status, b, c);
        WF.insertWorkForce(subContractors, noPeople, noHours);
        WD.insertWorkDetails(a1, W1, P1, b, c);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Row 1 has value only",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    else if ((W4 != null && W4.trim().length() > 0)) 
    {
        WD.insertWorkDetails(a1, W1, P1, b, c);
        WD.insertWorkDetails(a2, W2, P2, d, e1);
        WD.insertWorkDetails(a3, W3, P3, f, g);
        WD.insertWorkDetails(a4, W4, P4, h, i);
        ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather, date, status, c, b);
        WF.insertWorkForce(subContractors, noPeople, noHours);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All row have value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
}
```

In case 2, `c and W4!=null`, but I get `row 1 has value only`.

Comment: No problem, you're missing some closing brackets, I am assuming they went on the ends but left them off just in case.

Comment: Do you use a variable `i` somewhere else that is visible to this code? just noticed the method uses `ii` not sure if that's a coding typo or a typo when moving the code here - `onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) ` - could be why `i` isn't null and you go into the first `if` statement in case 1

Comment: @DoubleDouble I'm using Alert Dialog..The ii and i are not the same :)

Comment: Is `i` an `int`? where is it created? I would [debug `i` and `g`'s value if you know how](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html). You can step through the code line-by-line as it runs and see what each variable is, as well as see which `if` statements you are falling into

Comment: Kindly refer here http://i.stack.imgur.com/45hI5.png  . Ignore the imej on the left hand side... The value i is get from timePicker. I have another table used to store time in and time out.  Everytime the program run,  it will start checking from fourth row. If there are value in i,  it will save i to the ts. InsertTimeSheet... If no value found,  it will goes to row 3 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

At least there must be to closing braces at the end of your code.

Anyway, I see this structure of if-s:

```
if(...condition-1...) {
  ...code-1...
} esle if(...condition-2...) {
  if(...condition-3...){
    ...code-3...
  } else {
    ...code-4...
  }
}
```

Maybe You want "else" with code-4 to refer to "if" with condition-2, not to "if" with condition-3? Then You would change the structure in this way (additional } before else):

```
if(...condition-1...) {
  ...code-1...
} esle if(...condition-2...) {
  if(...condition-3...){
    ...code-3...
  } 
} else {
  ...code-4...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, There is no issue with if-else statement. May be, you are getting empty string with length > 0. TextUtils.isEmpty() : Returns true if the string is null or 0-length. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)